# Why I am getting an error of undefined index I am using jquery ajax

Tags: php, forms, jquery, modal-dialog

I don't why I am getting an error of undefined index. I think I properly send the value to php . Or Am I missing something in my code?

here's the jquery code I use:

```
$(function() {
            $('button').button();
            $('.update-profile-pic').click(function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    width:350,
                    modal:true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Upload': function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'upload-image.php',
                                method: 'post',
                                data: { uploadedfile: $('.profile-pic-name').val().trim() },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $('.new-profile-pic').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Here's my html code:

```
<button class="update-profile-pic">Update Profile Picture</button>
<div id="dialog">
    <p class="new-profile-pic">
        <!--Image should be here-->
    </p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
        <input class="profile-pic-name" name="uploadedfile" type="file">
    </form>
<div>
```

And here's my php code:

```
   <?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo '<img alt="" src="'.$target_path.'">';
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Here's the result of the firebug's console after I click the upload:

[image]

Here's the sample error ouput:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: Using your browser debugging tool what line does the error occur in? When using Chrome for example, errors are listed with information in which file they occur and on which line and so on. I'm sure other browser's tools are similar.

Comment: I use firebug in my response tab it says undefined index: uploadedfile

Answer (score 2):

Can you try   the following

```
       success: function(data) {

         $('.new-profile-pic').html(data.uploadedfile);

          }
```

Have u checked the following it's similar to what you are looking for

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but since you're using Ajax I don't think your PHP code will be looking for the file in the `$_FILE` global. Instead, the data will be in `$_POST` global (it'll be JSON so you will have to `json_decode()` it first). All that is going to be there though is the name of the file and not the actual file. You'll need to create a new `FormData` object in your JavaScript file and pass it a reference to the file input.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because you can't send files over AJAX. You will need to use a plugin or a hidden iFrame. See http://ramui.com/articles/ajax-file-upload-using-iframe.html for this.

Answer (score 0):

yeah @richoffrails as saying the file is not actually being uploading to the server check your 
$_FILES array for more info.

you can use this or many other are available for ajax file upload over the internet

http://www.uploadify.com/